# Running flask app on virtualenv inside docker container

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, flask, dockerfile

So I am trying to run a flask app inside of a virtualenv on a docker container.

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Gabriel Togni "togni@nmmi.edu"
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential python-virtualenv
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN virtualenv test

WORKDIR test

RUN /bin/bash -c "source test/bin/activate; pip install -r requirements.txt"

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash -c "source test/bin/activate; python app.py"
```

It builds with no errors, it runs with no errors, but it is not working.

My `requirements.txt` file only has `Flask==0.12.2`and my `app.py`looks like this

```
from flask import Flask
import sys
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
        if getattr(sys, "real_prefix", None) is not None:
                return "Maybe in a virtualenv"
        else:
                return "Probably not in a virtualenv"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I am trying to do this on an Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS

**EDIT--**

The problem was fixed after I added the `;` to my code on

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "source test/bin/activate; pip install -r requirements.txt"

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash -c "source test/bin/activate; python app.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

The entrypoint will be run in `WORKDIR`. Your file app.py is not on `/app`, which is your `WORKDIR`, it is on `/app/test`. You must send the path for the entrypoint command, as he doesn't find the file in current directory:

```
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash -c "source bin/activate python test/app.py"
```

Comment: Notice I have two `WORKDIR`. The first one is `/app` and the second one is `test`. Therefore, the `entrypoint` will be run on `WORKDIR test`

Comment: @GabrielLealTogni didn't notice that. You are right

Comment: @GabrielLealTogni what do you mean with "doesn't work"? Did you check the logs of the container?